# Moved joomla site to another host but doesn't work

Tags: joomla

I have recently moved my joomla site to another hosting. But now the site doesn't work. Shows blank page. Though the administrator's page (/administrator) is shown and works correctly. Have any ideas for what reason it can be?

Comment: In admin global configuration turn error reporting to development.  See what you get on the front end.

Comment: Shot in the dark: check the .htaccess file. If this was customized for the previous server it can cause this type of issue. If this was the case, there is little you can do on the admin side to get anything to show. Try just renaming this to something else and seeing if the front end loads.

Comment: there is nothing in error log, errors only e_notice .htaccess the default joomla's file, I even turned off the rewriting, so in .htaccess there is no configurations..on frontend the static pages are shown

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the .htaccess altogether
2. clear the cache and tmp folders
3. make sure db name, login and password are correct in the configuration.php
4. make sure the server path (tmp and logs folders) are correct
5. if you still get an empty page, make sure you're looking at the right log file.  Turn php error logging on or display them.
6. post some more details here...